# Retrieve a report on any duplicate rows of data in the emp table along with the count of -- the number of times that row of data is duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have EMP table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
[ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[MGR_ID] INT, 
[DEPT_ID] INT, 
[NAME] VARCHAR(30), 
[SAL] INT, 
[DOJ] DATE
);
```

I need to retrieve a report on any duplicate rows of data in the emp table along with the count of -- the number of times that row of data is duplicated.

I partially solved this:

This query returns a singe instance of each of the duplicated rows

```
SELECT [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ]
          from EMP 
          group by [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] 
         having count(*) > 1
```

the output will be:

```
MGR_ID  DEPT_ID NAME    SAL DOJ
NULL    2       Hash    100 2012-01-01
1       2       Robo    100 2012-01-01
2       1       Privy   50  2012-05-01
```

I still need to group this output by the number of times each of these rows are duplicated in the EMP table.

I tried this:

```
WITH CTE
AS 
(
SELECT * from EMP A
  join ( SELECT [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ]
           from EMP 
          group by [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] 
         having count(*) > 1 ) B
   on  a.[MGR_ID] = b.[MGR_ID]
   OR a.[MGR_ID] != b.[MGR_ID]
   AND a.[DEPT_ID] = b.[DEPT_ID]
   AND a.[NAME] = b.[NAME]
   AND a.[SAL] = b.[SAL]
   AND a.[DOJ] = b.[DOJ]
   )

   SELECT [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ], DENSE_RANK() OVER
   (PARTITION BY [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] ORDER BY DUPICATES) AS [DUPLICATES] 
   FROM CTE
```

But I got this error:

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The column 'MGR_ID' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'.

Please help.

The solution was partially found, except from I still need to do return MRG_ID column in the output for 3 records where it is = NULL

```
 with cte as
  (
SELECT A.[DEPT_ID],A.[NAME],A.[SAL],A.[DOJ] from EMP A
  join ( SELECT [DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ]
           from EMP 
           group by [DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] 
           having count(*) > 1 ) B

   ON a.[DEPT_ID] = b.[DEPT_ID]
   AND a.[NAME] = b.[NAME]
   AND a.[SAL] = b.[SAL]
   AND a.[DOJ] = b.[DOJ]
   )

   SELECT [DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ], DENSE_RANK() OVER
   (PARTITION BY [NAME] ORDER BY [NAME] DESC) AS [DUPLICATES], RANK() OVER
   (PARTITION BY [NAME] ORDER BY [NAME] DESC) AS [SimpleRank]
   FROM CTE 


DEPT_ID NAME    SAL DOJ        DUPLICATES   SimpleRank
2       Hash    100 2012-01-01  1            1
2       Hash    100 2012-01-01  1            1
2       Hash    100 2012-01-01  1            1
1       Privy   50  2012-05-01  1            1
1       Privy   50  2012-05-01  1            1
1       Privy   50  2012-05-01  1            1
2       Robo    100 2012-01-01  1            1
2       Robo    100 2012-01-01  1            1
2       Robo    100 2012-01-01  1            1
```

much

The final solution appears to be much easier:

```
Select [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ], count(name) From EMP group by [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] having Count(Name) >1
```

It produces this result set

```
MGR_ID  DEPT_ID NAME    SAL  DOJ       Count_Of_ Duplicated_Rows
NULL     2      Hash    100 2012-01-01      3
1        2      Robo    100 2012-01-01      3
2        1      Privy   50  2012-05-01      3
```

Note: This will work only if you group by column that is duplicated.

The example below is based on previous more complex query, but it validates all the fields in the row, in comparison to the simple query above that checks condition of a one particular column that you are grouping the query by.

```
WITH CTE 
    AS
    (
SELECT A.[MGR_ID], A.[DEPT_ID], A.[NAME], A.[SAL], A.[DOJ] 
FROM EMP A
JOIN   (SELECT [MGR_ID], [DEPT_ID], [NAME], [SAL], [DOJ]
        FROM EMP 
        GROUP BY [MGR_ID], [DEPT_ID], [NAME], [SAL], [DOJ] 
        HAVING count(*) > 1) B

       ON  a.[MGR_ID] = b.[MGR_ID]
       AND a.[DEPT_ID] = b.[DEPT_ID]
       AND a.[NAME] = b.[NAME]
       AND a.[SAL] = b.[SAL]
       AND a.[DOJ] = b.[DOJ]
   )

   SELECT [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ], 
   count(*) As Count_Of_Duplicated_Rows 
   FROM EMP 
   GROUP BY [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] 
   --HAVING Count(*) >1
```

Comment: You will get better help if you STOP YELLING. Typing in ALL CAPS is considered rude. Please edit your question.

Comment: Just an advice, edit your title so it is not  disrespectful.

Comment: `a.[MGR_ID] = b.[MGR_ID] OR a.[MGR_ID] != b.[MGR_ID]` - this is as good as not checking for either condition!

Comment: @enigma6205 is there any DUPICATES Column name in Table or is there any virtual column name like DUPICATES? No Column is Like that then How you are using that and The column 'MGR_ID' was specified multiple times for 'CTE' error is rectified by using specific column names instead of using *(All Columns) in OUTER QUERY.

Comment: Ajaynaidu Pappala, I have already tried changing (*) to this column list: [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ], but still the same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do not explicitly name the selected columns inside your CTE. Since both `EMP` and the subquery have a column called `MGR_ID`, doing `select *` on the join returns the column `MGR_ID` twice. According to [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx), this is not allowed:

> The list of column names is optional only if distinct names for all resulting columns are supplied in the query definition.

Note that you will encounter the same error for each pair of columns that exists on both sides of the join. To resolve this, you can either explicitly name the columns returned by the CTE in a column list with an alias for the repeated columns, like so:

```
WITH CTE (mgr_id,dept_id,name,sal,doj,mgr_id2,...) //mgr_id2 is an alias for b.mgr_id
AS
...
```

You can refer to this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d439c/1) for a demo. Remove the column list and you will see the same error you see now.

Alternatively, you can specify the columns to be selected in the CTE itself, I would recommend this since you don't actually need any repeated columns in your query:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT A.[MGR_ID],A.[DEPT_ID],A.[NAME],A.[SAL],A.[DOJ] from EMP A
  join ( SELECT [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ]
           from EMP 
          group by [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] 
         having count(*) > 1 ) B
...
```

Comment: Hi Shree,  I think I followed you recommendation, but still getting an error Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 228
Invalid column name 'DUPICATES'. The Query I'm running is

Comment: Do you have a column by that name? Also you need to be clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please, refer to my original post for the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH CTE
    AS 
    (
    SELECT a.* from EMP A
      join ( SELECT [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ]
               from EMP 
              group by [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] 
             having count(*) > 1 ) B
       on  a.[MGR_ID] = b.[MGR_ID]
       --OR a.[MGR_ID] != b.[MGR_ID]
       AND a.[DEPT_ID] = b.[DEPT_ID]
       AND a.[NAME] = b.[NAME]
       AND a.[SAL] = b.[SAL]
       AND a.[DOJ] = b.[DOJ]
       ),cte2 as(

       SELECT [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ], DENSE_RANK() OVER
       (PARTITION BY [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] ORDER BY [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ]) AS [DUPLICATES] 
       FROM CTE )
       select [MGR_ID],[DEPT_ID],[NAME],[SAL],[DOJ] from cte2 where DUPLICATES=1
```

Comment: I did try it already. It produces not a full scope of duplicates; it does not return the third duplicated row which has a NULL value in the MRG_ID column. Please see my explanation above.